# Is there any way to stop a mavenized build triggered from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven

Can be a dumb question But too curious to know a way or a plugin to do this.

I am triggering a mavenized project build through eclipse as

> Run As -> Maven build

So once i done it can it be aborted before it is getting completed ? Like Some times i forgot  to change some config so I want to redo . I know how to do it if it is triggered via cmd. But if there is way for this then it would be great ..

Answer (score 0):

The Maven build run should be displayed in the **Console** view. There should be a toolbar action (red square) in the Console view to terminate the run:

[image]

Comment: It didn't showed me anything in progress but my JUnit test cases where running at that time . It showed "No operations to display at this time."

Comment: Do you have the Console view open? And does the Maven build show any output in the Console view?